# Android webviews and loadData()

Tags: android, webview

I am developping an app which has to deal with several bitmaps, and display them
into a webview. The content of the webview can change if the user click a button.

Everything was working fine, i took the bitmaps, convert them in Base 64, no problem.

Then i decide change a little bit my code to be more organized, and now the webview
is only showing the content the first time then `loadData()` does nothing, even tho the parameter
htmlString contains a different HTML. I cant understand why the webview is not working anymore.

No error warnings from chromium, no exception, and im running `loadData()` from the UI Thread

Here is some pieces of code:

```java
// Load the pure html content, then calling loadData() with it
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(htmlProvider::doHTML)
                    .thenAccept(htmlText ->
                            runOnUiThread(() -> {webView.loadData(htmlText, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
                                                Logger.logV(htmlText);})) // Load data the first time, then do nothing even if html text has changed
                    .exceptionally(throwable -> {Logger.handleException(throwable); Logger.logV("ERROR"); return null;})
                    .thenRun(() -> {
                        Logger.logV("isLoading -> false");
                        isLoading = false;
                    });
```

`doHTML()` simply provide some html and takes care of loading bitmaps as Base64 into it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common problem with `loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)` method,
replace it with

> loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)

Comment: I'll try, but what do i provide for baseUrl ? null?

Comment: You can use "about:blank"

Comment: Ok it just works with null, thank you
Its strange, loadDAta was working perfectly, i just change the organization of the code in an abstraction layer an then boom, nothing, really strange